# Printing a special column in a file using awk

Tags: awk

I have a problem in printing a column that has names starting with ` (tick).

Below is the content in my file.

```
abc xyz pqr sym = `WST"    
abc xyz pqr sym = `WTFC"
abc xyz pqr sym = `WTI"
abc xyz pqr sym = `WTM"
abc xyz pqr sym = `WTR"
```

I want to print anything after the third column and I'm using the below code:

```
awk '{{printf "\n"} for(j=4;j<NF;++j){printf " %s",$j}}'
```

But,I'm not getting the expected output. Its not printing the last column. Could be because of tick character before the name. How can I make it to print the last column as well?

**OUTPUT:**

```
sym =
sym =
sym =    
sym =
sym =
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
sym = `WST"
sym = `WTFC"
sym = `WTI"
sym = `WTM"
sym = `WTR"
```

Comment: Here is my command: awk '{{printf "\n"} for(j=4;j<NF;++j){printf " %s",$j}}'

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're using `j < NF` instead of `j <= NF`

Since the field separator seems to be a single space, you could

```
cut -d " "  -f 4- file
```